# JSforce authentication popup dialog issue

Tags: javascript, rest-api

So I am working with JSforce lib and I am loging into SFDC by using this code which works perfectly but the problem is when the popup opens and get the access token in the URL nothing happens next the popup never closes and browser.on function never fires.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsforce/1.3.1/jsforce.min.js"></script>
<script>

jsforce.browser.init({
  clientId: '3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp7mLm_Hzhxc2gM.QMsZhKWDrFhNZ8zSJHS1rGKyuXrTR_XCszTknzUW_xA6mXSVtss9buDF',
  redirectUri: 'https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/JSForce_authrization',
  proxyUrl: 'https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/JSForce_authrization'
});

jsforce.browser.on('connect', function(conn) { 
    alert();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="jsforce.browser.login();">Login</button>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

The code above does call the authorization but the popup window does not close after it nor the browser.on fires any comments!!
[image]

Comment: So the trick is to disable the developer mode as it is a iframe and due to this the jsforce.js was not able to identify where to fire the "connect" event to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the Salesforce "Development Mode" or login as a user.

"Development Mode" is a reference to Salesforce Development Mode. See the following two pages for more information about it:

- https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_dev_mode.htm
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/visualforce_1.htm

Comment: A good way to know when to answer or comment is to consider how sure you are. If you are suggesting to "try" things, you're still debugging/analysing the issue and it's recommended to comment.

Comment: Thanks @Arun SFDC now the popup is closing as expected!!

Comment: Please mark as solved if my answer solved.

Comment: Hi @user614946, as Arun says, can you mark the answer as accepted if that fixed it? Also, can you clarify what it was? i.e. development mode/logging as another user.

Comment: "Development Mode" is a reference to Salesforce Development Mode.  See the following two links for details.  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_dev_mode.htm  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook.meta/workbook/visualforce_1.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'm author of JSforce, few comments :

- Why are you using `jsforce.browser` object in Visulaforce page ? `jsforce.browser` is needed for external web apps that needs to be authorized to access to Salesforce API via OAuth2. Visualforce pages are always authorized and can use access token (session id).

  var conn = new jsforce.Connection({ accessToken: "{!API.Session_Id}" });
- I'm not sure the implementation at the endpoint URL `proxyUrl` in `jsforce.browser.init`. It is used for specifying Salesforce Ajax Proxy compatible proxy service URL. As the same URL is specified in redirectUri, I'm doubting it is misused.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comments It really helped. The resion I used this approach as this page will be hosted through sites and a User might not be a User in my own org. Also I removed the proxy URL from my code. Thanks